# Join more than 2 database table in codeigniter Error : 1066

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

so i kinda new with codeigniter and im trying to join 3 table from my database

- database 1 : dkm (id, tgl, ref, etc)
- database 2 : order_product (kode_barang, packing, nama_barang, etc)
- database 3 : product (kodeprod, tglpakai, etc)

im already trying what other ppl do to join more than 2 table in codeigniter but i got this error :

> Error Number: 1066
>
> Not unique table/alias: 'order_product'

```
SELECT * 
      FROM `order_product` 
      JOIN `order_product` ON `order_product`.`kode_barang` = `dkm`.`id` 
      JOIN `order_product` ON `order_product`.`kode_barang` = `produksi`.`kodeprod`
```

This is my code :

*Bukaka_model.php*

```
    public function getOrderProduct()
        {
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('order_product');
            $this->db->join('order_product','order_product.kode_barang = dkm.id');
            $this->db->join('order_product','order_product.kode_barang = produksi.kodeprod');
            $query = $this->db->get();
            return $query->result();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to join to the same table multiple times, instead you need to join to the other tables once each.

You just need to change the names of the table you're joining to:

```
public function getOrderProduct()
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('order_product');
        $this->db->join('dkm','order_product.kode_barang = dkm.id');
        $this->db->join('produksi','order_product.kode_barang = produksi.kodeprod');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Comment: what if i want to select certain column from the database? if i select all it get error about cannot use object of type stdClass

Comment: That's unlikely to be related to selecting all columns (although can't be totally sure without the exact error and associated code)

but to select only specific columns you just need to change the `*` in the `select()`

Something like this:
`$this->db->select('order_product.someColumn', 'dkm.someColumn', 'produksi.someColumn', 'dkm,someOtherColumn')`

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

> Here, you have a mistake in joining tables, in `CI` `join()` in the first parameter you need to pass/write `table` name with you want to `join`

```
public function getOrderProduct()
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('order_product');
        $this->db->join('dkm','order_product.kode_barang = dkm.id');
        $this->db->join('produksi','order_product.kode_barang = produksi.kodeprod');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
           return $query->result();
        }else{
           return array();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:

public function getOrderProduct()
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('order_product');
        $this->db->join('dkm','dkm.id= order_product.kode_barang');
        $this->db->join('produksi',' produksi.kodeprod =  order_product.kode_barang');
        $query = $this->db->get();
           return $query->result();

    }
```

Comment: Please explain what you've changed and why - this helps others to learn from your answer

Comment: Additionally, can you explain why your answer looks so similar to the answer that M.Hemant has posted more than an hour before you?

Comment: not same see the join lines that is different from me and his

Comment: $this->db->join('dkm','dkm.id= order_product.kode_barang');
        $this->db->join('produksi',' produksi.kodeprod =  order_product.kode_barang');

Comment: i have changed this two lines first of all see properly then talk